# @OneToOne JPA - create ID on non parent side

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm use Spring Boot and trying to use @OneToOne JPA annotation . My class looks like this:

Primary Class

```
@Entity
public class User {
....
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "userID")
private ForeignProfile userForeignProfile;

}
```

Second Class:

```
@Entity
public class ForeignProfile {

@Id
private Long id; 
private Long userID;
.....
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "userForeignProfile")
private User user;

}
```

I want no additional columns to be created and this 2 tables to be connected using 'id' from User table and userID from ForeignProfile table. I tryed a lot of combination but cant make it work. The configuration I have shown here doesn nothing. What I'm doing wrong?

I tried using this examples but they don't do what I need
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one

Comment: That's not, at all, what your mapping does. It uses the user.id column as a join column (i.e. foreign key) to the foreignprofile.userID column. You want the reverse. Just read the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional

Comment: @JBNizet can you please give me code example? I tried reverse combination as well. I tried 7-8 different combination but no result at all.

Comment: I did. I posted a link. If you click on it, you'll find a complete example showing a OneToOne bidirectional association doing exactly what you want. Click the link, and read. And while you're at it, read the remaining of the documentation.

Comment: @JBNizet I tried that example but receive such error : Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.genb.model.ForeignProfile column: userID. (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false"). If I make it insertable false it means I need to update it from 2 queries not from 1

Comment: Because you shouldn't have any userID field. You already have user. It's sufficient. Just look at the example I linked to: there is no phoneId in PhoneDetails.